# How can i pass the value in float data type in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

this is my string i want to place the variable float point in this string:

i want to pass the value in data type of float.

such as..%.1f
%.2f
i want to pass the 1 and 2 value dynamically in iPhone sdk i use this code :-----

```
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.%if",[[arrayvalue objectAtIndex:0] intValue],[textField2.text floatValue]];
```

but it print only:--  .if

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest format string, you could do it like this:

```
int value = [[arrayvalue objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
NSString *string = [@"%." stringByAppendingFormat:@"%if", value];
string = [NSString stringWithFormat:string, [textField2.text floatValue]];
```

This is code is totally untested.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add Escape character for '%' this sign. 
Try below code it will work.

```
int i=2;
NSString *output= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%.%if",i];
```

if you want to display two values then you can try below.

```
int i=2;
float x=3.5;
NSString *output= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%.%if  %%.%ff",i,x];
```

Please modify as you need. This is just for your idea how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableString can add another string or format.

```
// array must have first object pass 1st parameter
NSMutableString *mutableString = [[NSString alloc] init];
[str appendFormat:"%d", [array objectAtIndex:0].intValue];

// array have second object then pass 2nd parameter
if (2 <= array.count)
   [mutableString appendFormat:"%f", [array objectAtIndex:0].floatValue]];

NSLog("%@", mutableString);
```

Comment: @Thanx booiljoung for response